# Route 53 going from www domain version to naked

Tags: amazon-route53

My domain used to use `www`, which I was ableto get rid of using Route 53. 
Now if I type `abcd.example`, it correctly shows what used to be on `www.abcd.example`.

The problem is, I have a handful of links  with the www version, which will no longer respond, although its routed to the EC2 instance.

What can I do with this?

Comment: *"will no longer respond"* needs to be explained using more technically precise terminology -- what *exactly* happens with these requests?

Comment: It looks like it was a cache problem :( it works fine now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has nothing to do with Route53. Your webserver needs to be configured to correctly serve requests for those domains.